# How to receive json from an array php in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm making a AJAX call and I'm trying to receive json from an array `json_encode()`, but doesn't seem to be working. Thanks for any help.

I'm not getting any errors and i've checked some other stackoverflow questions, but can't find a complete example.

The problem is i'm nothing it going in to the div (#form_response) when the ajax is called and its returning everything from `results`

The response I get using the code below is:

```
{"success":true,"error":false,"complete":"<div class=\"ser_mess\">success<\/div>","error_msg":{"empty":"<div class=\"ser_mess\">empty<\/div>"}}
```

HTML & AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="" id="form_response"></div>

<form id="add_property_form" action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="input">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#add_property_form").submit(function(evt){  

      evt.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
   $.ajax({
       url: 'thescript.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache:false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       dataType: "json",

    success: function (data) {
    $('#form_response').html(data);
    }

  });
return false;
});

</script>
```

thescript.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$success = true;
$false = false;



$results = array(
   'success' => $success,
   'complete' => '<div class="ser_mess">success</div>',
   'error' => $false,
   'error_msg' => array('empty' => '<div class="ser_mess">empty</div>',)
);

if(empty($_POST['input']) ){

$results['error'];
$results['error_msg']['empty'];


}else{

$results['success'];
$results['complete'];

}


echo json_encode($results);
exit();
```

Comment: You are getting the JSON so what's the problem?

Comment: Do you want the raw JSON string to put into the div#form_response?

Comment: should I not do that?

Comment: you can - it depends what you want it to do? i'm assuming you want one of the little snippets of HTML from your JSON response to appear in the div#form_response? i've posted an answer below based upon my assumption of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My testing steps with your code. Resolving problems.**

- If you are submitting the data with an ajax request, then you don't want to natively submit the form. So, use just a button of type "button", not of type "submit". Statements like `evt.preventDefault();` and `return false` are correctly used only when the form should be natively submitted (e.g. not through a button of type "submit", or similar) and, for example, you are validating it. If the user input is not valid, then you apply such statements, so that you can stop the form from submitting.
- Your ajax doesn't start, because it's not included into a `$(document).ready(function () {...}`.
- I receive *"TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData*. Use `var formData = $('add_property_form').serialize();` instead of `var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);`.
- The `async:false` property gave the warning: *"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:15845"*. So, remove `async`. Also, you don't need `cache`, `contentType`, `processData`. Remove them.
- Since, by setting `dataType: "json"`, you are already telling the server that you are expecting JSON encoded data back from the server, you don't need to send the response header with `header('Content-Type: application/json');`. Remove it.
- Use `method: "post"` instead of `type: "post"`, because the latter is used only up to version 1.9.0 of jquery. Read the [ajax specification](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).
- Your php code inside the *if statements* was error-prone. I made my version out of it.
- If you are receiving JSON encoded data from the server, you can not directly pass it as html content into a div. You must read its values separately and do something with them. In analogy: in php you can also not simply write `echo $results`, because then you would receive `Notice: Array to string conversion`. The same is with the client-side code.

#### test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title></title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#add_property_form").submit(function (evt) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    var formData = $('#add_property_form').serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'thescript.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: formData,
                        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            var formResponse = $('#form_response');
                            var success = data.success;
                            var message = data.message;

                            if (success) {
                                formResponse.removeClass('error').addClass('success');
                            } else {
                                formResponse.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
                            }

                            formResponse.html(message);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(jqXHR);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .success,
            .error {
                max-width: 400px;
                color: white;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
            }

            .success {
                background-color: green;
            }

            .error {
                color: white;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="form_response" class="message"></div>

        <form id="add_property_form" action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="input">
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### thescript.php

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST['input'])) {
    $results['success'] = false;
    $results['message'] = 'No input value provided!';
} else {
    $results['success'] = true;
    $results['message'] = 'You provided the value ' . $_POST['input'];
}

echo json_encode($results);
exit();
```

---

**Another example**

Since you were looking for a complete example I took the liberty to create one for you.

The main point of it is to define an "error" callback for the ajax request. Because, when you throw errors, you actually want your ajax "error" callback take its role. For activating it, you just have to send a custom response header - having a status code of class *"4xx: Client errors"* - from the server (`search.php`) to the client (`custom.js`). Such a header is used like this: *"Dear browser, I, the server, am sending you this response: 'HTTP/1.1 420 Please provide the city.'. As you see, its status code is 420, e.g. of class 4xx. So please be so kind and handle it in the 'error' callback of your ajax request"*. Here is the [List ofStatus Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors).

You can run the code as it is. Create a folder in your document root, paste the files in it, then let `test.php` running.

#### test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <!-- CSS resources -->
        <link href="custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- JS resources -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="page-container">

            <form class="user-input">
                <div class="messages">
                    Here come the error/success messages
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="city">City:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" id="searchButton" name="submit" value="search">
                        Search
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div class="cities">
                Here comes the list of the found cities
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### search.php

```
<?php

// Get the posted values.
$city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : '';

// Validate the posted values.
if (empty($city)) {
    /*
     * This custom response header triggers the ajax error because the status
     * code begins with 4xx (which corresponds to the client errors). Here is
     * defined "420" as the custom status code. One can choose whatever code
     * between 401-499 which is not officially assigned, e.g. which is marked
     * as "Unassigned" in the official HTTP Status Code Registry. See the link.
     *
     * @link https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml HTTP Status Code Registry.
     */
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 Please provide the city.');
    exit();
} /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

/* The user input is valid. */

/*
 * Perform the search operation in a database, for example, and get the data.
 * Here just an array simulating a database result set with two records.
 */

$foundCities = [
    [
        'name' => 'Athens',
        'isCapital' => 'is a capital',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Constanta',
        'isCapital' => 'is not a capital',
    ],
];

// Print the response.
$response = [
    'message' => 'Great. ' . count($foundCities) . ' cities were found.',
    'cities' => $foundCities,
];

echo json_encode($response);
exit();
```

#### custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchButton').click(function (event) {
        ajaxSearch();
    });
});

function ajaxSearch() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'search.php',
        data: $('.user-input').serialize(),
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            /*
             * Just for testing: diplay the whole response
             * in the console. So look unto the console log.
             */
            console.log(response);

            // Get the success message from the response object.
            var successMessage = response.message;

            // Get the list of the found cities from the response object.
            var cities = response.cities;

            // Display the success message.
            displayMessage('.messages', 'success', successMessage);

            // Display the list of the found cities.
            $('.cities').html('');
            $.each(cities, function (index, value) {
                var city = index + ": " + value.name + ' (' + value.isCapital + ')' + '<br/>';
                $('.cities').append(city);
            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Handle the raised errors. In your case, display the error message.
            handleAjaxError(jqXHR);
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            // ... Do something here, after all ajax processes are finished.
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Display a user message.
 *
 * @param selector string The jQuery selector of a message container.
 * @param type string The message type: success|danger|warning.
 * @param message string The message text.
 * @return void
 */
function displayMessage(selector, type, message) {
    $(selector).html('<div class="message ' + type + '">' + message + '</div>');
}

/**
 * Handle an error raised by an ajax request.
 *
 * If the status code of the response is a custom one (420), defined by
 * the developer, then the corresponding error message is displayed.
 * Otherwise, e.g. if a system error occurres, the displayed message must
 * be a general, user-friendly one. So, that no system-related infos will be shown.
 *
 * @param jqXHR object The jQuery XMLHttpRequest object returned by the ajax request.
 * @return void
 */
function handleAjaxError(jqXHR) {
    var message = 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again, or contact us.';

    if (jqXHR.status === 420) {
        message = jqXHR.statusText;
    }

    displayMessage('.messages', 'danger', message);
}
```

#### custom.css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}

.page-container {
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.messages {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.message {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.success {
    color: #3c763d;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
}

.danger {
    color: #a94442;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
    background-color: #f2dede;
}

.warning {
    color: #8a6d3b;
    border-color: #faebcc;
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
}

form {
    width: 400px;
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-group label {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 40px;
}

button {
    padding: 7px 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #8daf15;
}
```

Comment: Can this be used to upload files?

Comment: @bob If you ask: _"Can I upload files using ajax requests?"_, then the answer is yes. Search for _"ajax upload"_ or similar. The ajax request should not be much different from mine. Important is the _enctype_, or _contentType_, or so. It should be _"multipart/form-data"_, either on ajax or on the _form_ tag. Search for _"ajax enctype"_, or _"ajax contentType"_, or _"ajax multipart/form-data"_. But, if you want to make file uploads, then I strongly suggest you to use a jquery plugin. With [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) I worked thoroughly with it and it's a very good plugin.

Comment: Dear Downvoter, I am very curious to find out the reasons of your downvote. Please explain them to me. At least out of courtesy! P.S: What I find very interesting is, that all our answers, plus the original question, were downvoted at the same time. Nicely done...

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#form_response').html(data);
}
```

this block is your response handler - and `data` is the JSON object you're getting back from the AJAX call. if you want to display a particular attribute of your JSON object, you'll want to reference something like `data.complete`, which looks like a little bit of HTML, which you can then put into `your div#form_response`

```
success: function (data) {
        $('#form_response').html(data.success);
}
```

you can access all of the object in the same way:

```
{"success":true,"error":false,"complete":"<div class=\"ser_mess\">success<\/div>","error_msg":{"empty":"<div class=\"ser_mess\">empty<\/div>"}}
```

so to get the html for the "empty" error message, you'd use

```
$('#form_response').html(data.error_msg.empty);
```

alternatively, if i misunderstand the question, if you want the RAW json to appear in `div#form_response`, you can convert the json object into a string:

```
json_string = JSON.stringify( data );
$('#form_response').html( json_string );
```

Comment: So how would you get a message from `error_msg` array? - I got it.

Comment: So you have to reference every single response? with a  switch statement

Comment: i've updated the answer. you can use dot notation to access each of the variables, i.e. data.error_msg.empty - although, i'd suggest not passing HTML in the ajax calls, let your front-end handle display, and the serverside just say whether something worked or not.

Comment: what do you want to appear in the div#form_response? the raw ajax? or the content from the ajax response?

Comment: the contents of the ajax response. so if it's empty it'll return the `<div class="ser_mess">empty</div>`

Comment: if you just want the ajax response, as a string, use "text" as your dataType in the $.ajax call, or JSON.stringify() the data object you get back from the AJAX call.

Comment: Bob, you should be doing "response" or "HTML" in your array before you Json encode it. Make it so success AND error both use "response" or "HTML" as key for response array. This will let you always show the response HTML no matter what, as your script will send data same way each time.

Comment: @Nerdi.org sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @MatthewKnight this part `$('#form_response').html(data.error_msg.empty);` doesn't return the data in to the div.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly confident this should work for you :)

Your HTML/JS file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="" id="form_response"></div>

<form id="add_property_form" action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="input">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#add_property_form").submit(function(evt){  

      evt.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
   $.ajax({
       url: 'thescript.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache:false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       dataType: "json",

    success: function (data) {
    var resultData = data.response_msg; // get HTML to insert
    $('#form_response').html(resultData);
    // You can also use data.status (= true or false), to let you know which HTML was inserted :) 
    }

  });
return false;
});

</script>
```

your PHP file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// construct original array
$results = array(
   'status' => false,
   'response_msg' => ''
);

// analyze $_POST variables 
if(empty($_POST['input'])){ // if input post is not empty:
 $results['status'] = false; 
 $results['response_msg'] = '<div class="ser_mess">empty</div>';
}else{ // if input post is empty: 
 $results['status'] = true; 
 $results['response_msg'] = '<div class="ser_mess">success</div>';
}


echo json_encode($results); // encode as JSON
exit();
```